# How to make a ko.computed trigger

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have this ko.computed:

```
ko.computed(function () {
    var index = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Scenes(), function (scene) {
        var jcount = 0;
        scene.sequenceNo(); // I thought this would trigger it, but it doesn´t!
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(scene.Textbatches(), function (batch) {
            batch.sequenceNoInProject(index);
            batch.sequenceNo(jcount);
            index++;
            jcount++;
        });
    });
});
```

where

```
Scene = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    //...
    self.sequenceNo = ko.observable(data.sequenceNo);
   self.Textbatches = ko.observableArray(); // Array holding allocated text bathes
};
```

and
    self.Scenes is created as an array of Scene-instances.

What I want is the sequenceNo of the textbatches allocated to scenes to be calculated when
a) text batches are dragged around (and this works)
b) Scenes are rearranged in a new order (drag and drop 2nd scene at the top).

b) Does not work and my idea was that the ko.computed should trigger when the value of self.Scenes().sequenceNo() change...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/6xwwuonp/9/

Any hints and suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: @manji idea is correct . but can you share some more info how your view model will look (so question looks complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty obvious when it just came to mind. The ko.computed triggered all along but it didn´t acknowledge the fact that the self.Scenes()-array was unaltered even though it was sorted in the accordion and the sequenceNo was updated.

Adding

```
self.Scenes().sort(function(a,b){
            return a.sequenceNo() < b.sequenceNo() ? -1 : a.sequenceNo() > b.sequenceNo() ? 1 : a.sequenceNo() == b.sequenceNo() ? 0 : 0;
        });
```

in the beginning of the computed did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a call to `trigger()` within the computed observable, that will register a dependency on it:

```
ko.computed(function () {
    var index = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Projects(), function (item) {
        var jcount = 0;
        item.trigger(); // <-- here
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.tasks(), function (task) {
            task.sequenceNoGlobal(index);
            task.sequenceNoLocal(jcount);
            index++; jcount++;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, manji. I tried this (in a couple of variants) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the parenthesis may work (item.tasks)

```
ko.computed(function () {
    var index = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Projects(), function (item) {
        var jcount = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.tasks, function (task) {
            task.sequenceNoGlobal(index);
            task.sequenceNoLocal(jcount);
            index++; jcount++;
        });
    }); 
});
```

Or, whenever you update tasks use the valueHasMutated().

```
this.tasks.valueHasMutated();
```

A better pattern is to get a reference to our underlying array, push to it, then call .valueHasMutated(). Now, our subscribers will only receive one notification indicating that the array has changed.
http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: The question was how to make this computed depend on a different observable, changing how the `tasks` observable array is accessed will have no impact.  Also, there is no difference between `item.tasks()` and `item.tasks` here.  In one case, you're relying on the function you're calling to unwrap the observable for you.  In the other, you're doing it yourself and assuming it's an observable.  The safest way to do it would be:  `ko.unwrap(item.tasks)`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make a lot of sense, I think you should take a step back and evaluate your problem first.  You can trigger a computed in a few different ways, one way is to add `item.trigger()` into the computed and, outside of it, change the trigger.  Make sure you *change* it, in other words, assign a new value.  Because if you just always do `something.trigger(true)` it will only trigger the computed the first time.

But the main point is, the computed would recompute, but if it doesn't actually depend on the value of `trigger`, it will return the same result.  If your item's `tasks` are changing, it would also trigger and that dependency would make sense.  So either take another look at how observables and computeds work or put up a jsfiddle explaining the problem if it's more complicated than we're assuming.

Comment: Here´s a fiddle illustrating the challenge: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/6xwwuonp/7/

Comment: I'm sorry, that's over 600 lines of code.  I'm nice but nobody's *that* nice :)  If you'd like me to take a look, please reduce it to the smallest amount of code that illustrates your problem.